# Adding button to Slack Channel Message using Zapier Integration

Tags: button, slack, zapier

Does anyone know of a way to add interactive buttons to a slack channel messages that are created using the Zapier slack channel message integration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but that's not currently possible. Because of the way button interactions are handled (centrally, to a single url for all buttons created with Zapier), we haven't come up with a good way for users to add buttons to their messages that would be in any way useful.

We track all feature requests that come in through tickets, so if you'd like to voice your support and get notified if/when this does get implemented, I'd suggest emailing in to `contact@zapier.com`.

Comment: Thanks David. I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: You guys need to have a solution for this.

Comment: Honestly should just parse markdown links as buttons, or even make a special markdown syntax for them like {Button Name}(https://...)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add buttons, but you need a **premium account**. It works by using the [Zapier webhook function](https://zapier.com/page/webhooks/) to send a POST request directly to the Slack API.

1. You can follow [this tutorial](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#getting_started__1.-create-a-slack-app-if-you-dont-have-one-already) to prepare everything in Slack
2. Then you need to add a custom request step in Zapier:
   [Screenshot from Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Bfo.png)
3. Select method "POST" and paste the URL from your [Slack application management tool](https://api.slack.com/apps)
4. Build your Slack message using the [Slack Block Kit Builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/)
5. Paste the JSON from the Block Kit Builder into the data field in Zapier
6. Replace text from JSON with dynamic fields from Zapier where necessary

Likely if you want to have buttons, you would want to use them to trigger further Zapier events. For this, follow these steps:

1. Create new Zap triggered by Webhooks by Zapier
2. Select "Catch requests"
3. Copy Request URL
4. Navigate to your [Zapier application management tool](https://api.slack.com/apps) and find your app's Interactive Components section
5. Paste Request URL from Zapier